# How to boost bluetooth range?

Tags: bluetooth

I have had some success connecting to my Bluetooth devices but only when I'm in the same room as the Rpi. This limits the utility somewhat... I had hoped to be able to use them anywhere in my home. I will (eventually) move the Rpi into a more central location, but I don't think that it will give me sufficient range.

I would like what seems to be 15-25 meters (max) through drywall/lumber walls on a single floor.

It's my understanding that the Rpi 3 does have an unpopulated antenna connector, but that this is only for the wifi (I use ethernet).

Are there any USB adapters that might solve this problem? The only ones I can find on Amazon are those low profile ones that stick out a quarter of an inch. I can't imagine those will be a superior option (probably just for keyboards/mice a few inches away?).

Comment: What Bluetooth devices are you connecting?

Comment: @CoderMike For now, a blood glucose monitor. Soon, several others (blood pressure, bathroom scale). The bathroom scale may actually be close enough that it's not the issue, but the others I don't want to traipse to the other side of the house to use. It also somehow picked up my FIXD obd2 device in the car, which I didn't even know was on while the engine was off... might be interesting to be able to use that, though I don't think that's feasible really.

Answer (score 3):

Bluetooth shares an antenna with WiFi, and for this reason Bluetooth on a USB dongle may have better range performance than the in-built BT antenna.

The other thing that will help is ***elevation***. This is due to *RF-propagation* and *laws-of-physics* reasons unrelated to Raspberry Pi. But if you can put any antenna a little higher (on a shelf, mounted high on the wall or ceiling) it will reduce *RF path loss*, and thereby improve range performance.

There is also a ***possibility*** you ***may*** be able to change the transmit power from the command line. I have not tried this, so proceed at your own risk. Here are some references to get started:

- [Linux SE Q&A: How to set Bluetooth transmit power?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/58510/how-to-set-bluetooth-transmit-power) has some ideas & avenues for additional research, but is years old now. The `bccmd` command is a default install on my RPi 4.
- [SO Q&A: Change Tx Bluetooth Linux No Effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34132324/change-tx-bluetooth-linux-no-effect) has an answer that states that according to BT specs: `only class 1 devices can change the transmitting power level by software`. A quick search in an effort to learn if the RPi BT hardware is `class 1` yielded nothing. However - **this is worth keeping in mind if you decide to purchase a BT dongle.**

Answer (score 1):

Im pretty sure any Modern Bluetooth adapter would be better then what the pi comes with (Modern aka Bluetooth V4.0+)

I use this 
https://www.gearbest.com/digital-antenna/pp_009944368401.html?wid=1433363&currency=ILS&vip=4446207&gclid=Cj0KCQiAxNnfBRDwARIsAJlH29Br_ivnwzXQQJUE9hGHG8Ng9QLgCWIzU-za1hGQkXaDrKyU9zPfU6QaAhbHEALw_wcB
on my windows machine it can go through a single brick wall in total its like 7 Meters...
the best I could find was a 2in1 (with wifi) but still cant tell if it will handle those walls better, the only way to find out is reading reviews...
https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1200M-Wireless-WiFi-USB3-0-AC-Dual-Band-2-4Ghz-5-8GHz-Adapter-with-Bluetoot-4/32920319446.html?spm=2114.search0104.3.213.5823156epzBv1i&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_5_5734715_10065_10068_5734615_319_5734815_317_10696_10924_453_10084_454_10083_10618_10920_10921_10307_10922_537_536_10059_10884_10887_100031_321_322_10103_5734515,searchweb201603_51,ppcSwitch_0&algo_expid=fc4ed9da-62bd-4834-98b2-d19ded3f623b-33&algo_pvid=fc4ed9da-62bd-4834-98b2-d19ded3f623b